# MySQL slow on UPDATE with IN on large data set

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to update a main dataset by various sources that provide for some of the existing records some changes, like new mobile phone number.

The execution time of every query is above 10 hours.

Environment: MySQL 8, 8 Core CPU, 32 GB Memory.

I have the following main table, it holds atm 3M records:

```
CREATE TABLE `contact_data` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `email_status` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `mobile_phone` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `nickname` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `country` (`country`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

So far I have try to make updates in various ways. The source tables have mostly only 10K - 100K records. I have try the same with MyISAM and "id" as Primary key.

**Join:**

```
UPDATE contact_data cd
LEFT JOIN (SELECT email, firstname FROM source2 WHERE firstname <> '' GROUP BY email ORDER BY id DESC) AS t2
ON cd.email = t2.email
SET cd.firstname = t2.firstname
```

**Direct:**

```
UPDATE contact_data SET mobile_phone = (SELECT phone FROM source1 WHERE email = contact_data.email ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) 
WHERE mobile_phone IS NULL
```

Direct with limit of records:

```
UPDATE contact_data SET mobile_phone = (SELECT phone FROM source1 WHERE email = contact_data.email ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) 
WHERE mobile_phone IS NULL 
AND email IN (SELECT DISTINCT email FROM source1)
```

**Config:**

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16G
innodb_log_file_size = 512M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_buffer_size = 10M

key_buffer_size = 512M
```

More tuning of config files would mostly bring small improvement.

Is there anything that I can try?

Comment: Do you have an index on email in your source tables?

Comment: I see you have a left join in your join query - is that a typo?

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE contact_data; B) SHOW CREATE TABLE source2; C) SHOW CREATE TABLE source1; D) RAM, cores, any data on SSD or NVME devices?  E) SELECT @@innodb_io_capacity;

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes I have a Index on email in Source tables, the LEFT JOIN was it seems my mistake, as soon I removed LEFT the most queries take a few seconds, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to prepare source table by remove email duplicates and add PRIMARY/UNIQUE index on email field.

Second, because your source table more smaller from primary you can use next query:

```
UPDATE source s
JOIN contact_data cd ON s.email = cd.email
SET cd.mobile_phone = s.mobile_phone;
```

Third you can improve update performance by tune MySQL configuration using [mysqltuner](https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl) or any other instrument

Comment: Thank you this approach would surely give some performance improvement but involve work for prepration, the solution for my problem was to go with simple JOIN instead LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @nenad007 Congratulations on your simple solution to higher performance.  Only use LEFT join when you have a good reason.